# Is is possible to use pyinstaller to build the exe with my own icon?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller 2.0 and python 2.7 to build a onedir exe from my pyqt application.  Everything works well... the exe runs and shows the specified icon in the progam bar, but the icon shown for the exe is still the pyinstaller icon.

Is is possible to use pyinstaller to build the exe with my own icon?

My build command is:

```
c:\python27\python.exe c:\pyinstaller\pyinstaller.py --noconsole --icon="myprog.ico" --out="C:\out" "C:\out\myprog.py"
```

I have already tried modifying the exe section of the spec-file to include "icon='myicon.ico'", but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, resolved by installing pywin32

Comment: That was it ... your awesome!